# Form POST HTML with same fields

Tags: html, css, django

I have a form that has 2 inputs but with the same name `banana`.
However each line has a different value for fruit.number.

**Django Template**

```
{% for fruit in response %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ fruit.number }}</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="banana" class="update_input">
                        <option selected="selected">yes</option>
                        <option value="false">no</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

        {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" style="color:black;">
</form>
```

When I POST I post the banana value twice. But I need to differentiate these values based on the `fruit.number`.

What options do I have. From what I can see the main option is to add the fruit number to the name of the select i.e

```
<select name="1_banana" class="update_input">
      <option value="true" selected="selected">yes</option>
      <option value="false">no</option>
</select>
```

Is there anyway to have a nested POST like `{1 : {"banana":"false"}}` ?

Hope this all makes sense : )

Thanks,

Comment: you may write twice  `<select name="banana[]">` so you could receive an array, e.g. `banana => ["false", "true"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only option id to append `{{ fruit.number }}` to your select name:

```
{% for fruit in response %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ fruit.number }}</td>
    <td>
      <select name="banana_{{ fruit.number }}" class="update_input">
        <option value="true" selected="selected">yes</option>
        <option value="false">no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

/*
POST:
[
  'banana_1': 'true',
  'banana_2': 'false'
]
*/
```

Notes:

- don't forget to add a `value` attribute on your "yes" option
- there's a missing `</tr>` (just a notice, could be a typo)

There's a option which allows you to have multiple values for a same name:

```
<select name="banana[]" class="update_input">
```

Unfortunately, you won't be able to differentiate both fruits values, unless you distinguish them in your code:

```
{% for fruit in response %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ fruit.number }}</td>
    <td>
      <select name="banana[]" class="update_input">
        <option value="{{ fruit.number }}_true" selected="selected">yes</option>
        <option value="{{ fruit.number }}_false">no</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

/*
POST:
[
  'banana': [ '1_true, '2_false' ]
]
*/
```